# "SELECT EXISTS" giving incorrect result, corrects upon resetting connection

Tags: mysql, mysql-connector

I'm connected to a MySQL server on two different connections. On one of them, I can execute:

```
query = 'SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN = "VALUE")'
c.execute(query)
In: c.fetchall()[0][0]
Out: 1
```

Connected through a second machine, using identical values, I get the following:

```
 query = 'SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN = "VALUE")'
 c.execute(query)
 In: c.fetchall()[0][0]
 Out: 0
```

The only thing that seems to fix it is closing the connection and restarting it. It is causing some problems. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: This might be a transaction issue. Did you add, change or delete the "value"-entry during one of those "connections"? Which connection(s) did you restart in order to make it work again?

Comment: @Solarflare Yeah I added the value, and I restarted the second connection (the one whose query resulted in 0 for `SELECT EXISTS`) to make it work again

Comment: Then my guess is still a [transaction issue](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html) (e.g. the 2nd transaction might not see the changes done by the 1st transaction, especially if you queried for this value/table before that code fragment). Unfortunately, your question does not contain enough code to verify this nor to fix it nor do we know if you need or want a transaction, but you might want to check if you are using transactions (e.g. by autocommit = 0), and add more code/details if you need further help investigating or fixing.

Answer (score 0):

Logically speaking, the same exists query with the same underlying data should return the same result on all machines.  However, I see a problem with your query.  You are using double quotes around `VALUE`, which you intend to be a string literal.  This could be causing MySQL to view `VALUE` as an identifier (e.g. as a column).  Try using *single* quotes instead:

```
query = "SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN = 'VALUE')"
c.execute(query)
In: c.fetchall()[0][0]
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to have fixed it :(

Comment: Then you should add sample data to your question and make this problem reproducible.  I see no other explanation for what you are seeing, other than the double quotes issue.